# How to Update Column of one table if Another table column value becomes zero In Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have two tables of **ITEM**(*Menu_Id,Menu_Status*) & **STOCK**(*Stock_Id,Menu_Id,Stock_Quantity*).

Now I want to update the Menu_Status column of **ITEM table**, when the Stock_Quantity column of **STOCK table** value will be zero.
And also I implement this on Oracle Apex 5.0 .

I want to handle this in backend of database, when customer orders and Stock_Quantity will be minus(-) according to number of quantity is ordered.

Which one better for this? Trigger or Procedure? Please help me by providing code.
[image]

I tried this code but having ORA-24344: success with compilation error message!

```
create or replace trigger "KITCHEN_T11"
AFTER
insert or update on "KITCHEN"
for each row
when (NEW.quantity<= 0)
begin
declare
mid number;
begin
select m_id into mid from kitchen where k_id=:new.k_id;
update menu_item set status=0 where m_id=mid;
end;
end;
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a trigger.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: tried but having no good knowledge on PL SQL as well as no time to solved this problem. I just feel that i need that type of solution. That's it !
@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I just need a structure of the code to find the way to solve my problem.
If anyone help me a little bit then my time will be solved. As i need to submit my project in university.
Hope that you understood. Dont know why you are reacted rather than helping!!!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Within a row-level trigger you already have access to all of the attributes of the row being processed, so you don't need to query `KITCHEN`, and that is not allowed anyway. Also the enclosing `begin ... end` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should anyhow write a procedure to update item table. Only choice need to make is to call it from where.

If you know all the process who are updating stock table, and if this procedure can be placed there, it will be best option.

In case it is not possible, you can call this procedure from trigger.

Comment: Success with compilation error...
create or replace trigger "KITCHEN_T11"
AFTER
insert or update on "KITCHEN"
for each row
when (NEW.quantity<= 0)
begin
declare
mid number;
begin
select m_id into mid from kitchen where k_id=:new.k_id;
update menu_item set status=0 where m_id=mid;
end;
end;

Comment: avoid using select m_id into mid from kitchen where k_id=:new.k_id; use new keyword like you are using in where clause

Comment: thanks ... solved this problem.. avoiding query as you said and also correct my column name of Menu_Item

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "STOCK_T1" 
AFTER
insert or update on "STOCK"
for each row
 WHEN (NEW.stock_quantity<= 0)

begin
update item set menu_status=0 where menu_id=:NEW.MENU_ID;
end;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!